# От чего может глючить анимация (во всех браузерах) на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools

Стоит joomla 2.5. У нее mootols библиотека скриптов. Я же подключил и использую jquery-1.8.3. Сделал noConflict. Возможности убрать полностью mootols нет к сожалению.

На сайте много анимированных объектов. Но анимации в один момент времени много нет. Т.е. нажал, что-то выехало. Ничего сложного.

Почему-то вся анимация глючная, как простая и и сложная. Дерганая... На компьютере по мощнее, это не так заметно, а там где не очень мощный, глюканы прямо!

Факт фактом, даже на мощном компьютере тормоза во время воспроизведения анимации.

Кроме того, что это все наверно из-за mootols у меня идей нет( В чем еще проблема то может быть?

ЗЫ Если в Google Chrome открыть панель разработчика, то анимация еще в 10 раз хуже начинает работать. Как слайды( Смотрю на другие сайты, там где очень сложная анимация, в раз 5 сложнее и больше объектов двигается, то там работает без единого глюка!

Буду рад любой помощи, замучался с поисками проблемы.